# Update TextView in inflated Layout

Tags: android, textview, layout-inflater

I have a template layout file called

```
template_dashboard_item.xml
```

its contents are

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" style="@style/DashboardItemContainer">
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" style="@style/DashboardItem">
    <TextView style="@style/DashboardItemText" android:text="Application for Jane Doe has been added" android:textColor="@color/black" />
    <TextView style="@style/DashboardItemText" android:text="Added today at ..." android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />                 
</LinearLayout>
```

I am using this template layout by inflating it and inserting it into a view like so

```
LinearLayout item = (LinearLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.template_dashboard_item, items, false);
items.addView(item);
```

Like that, I am inserting it multiple times.

I would like to know, before I insert it (addView) how to I update the TextViews (text) that are there ?

In other words how do I fetch the objects for the TextView ? (I guess findViewById would not work in this case).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why can't you add an id to your two text views in the XML and use `TextView text = item.findViewById(R.id.your_id);`

Comment: Oh I thought findViewById is only on the activity and does not work on the scope of a particular View. Brilliant ! Just what I needed. Shall give this a go.

Comment: @PrakashRaman Yep, this method is also available on any object which extends `View`

Comment: Thanks ! Worked perfectly !

Answer (score 1):

you can either assign an id to the `TextView`s and use `item.findViewById` to retrieve it, or use  `ViewGroup.getChildAt(int index)`

```
 for (int i = 0 i < item.getChildCount(); i++) {
         View view = item.getChildAt(i);
         if (view instanceof TextView) {

         }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you create a custom layout like this

```
public class CustomView extends RelativeLayout {

    private TextView header;
    private TextView description;



    public Card(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public Card(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public Card(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        inflate(getContext(), R.layout.view_layout, this);
        this.header = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.header);
        this.description = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.description);
    }


    public void setHeader(String header) {
        this.header.setText(header);
    }


    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description.setText(description);
    }

}
```

And to add the layout

```
LinearLayout items = (LinearLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.template_dashboard_item, items, false);
CustomView item = new CustomView(this);
item.setHeader("xxx);
item.setDescription("yyy");
items.addView(item);
```

Comment: Thanks :) Will definitely consider this approach in the future.